# create sub yml files in visual studio

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017

I couldn't find a way to create sub yml files like override.yml to seperate settings of staging and production

I tried to create files manually in file system and tried to edit `docker-compose.dcproj` but visual studio keeps overriding my changes.

Comment: If you expect any kind of useful answer at least include some information about your setup; what you have tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: I couldn't find anything else to try other than what I told in my question

Comment: You haven't even included any information about what you're trying to to. Why you have YML file, why you have a docker-compose file, what you project does or anything ... really. As it is the obvious answer would be for you to implement code that accepts an override file.